# Changing the order of divisions when the resolution is below a certain amount of pixels

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is more or less on the simpler side.
The way it works is that the content blocks will change order depending on which resolution you are viewing the webpage from.

Right now I am checking via **jQuery** if the resolution meets the right requirements. Let's say the screen width is below 1200, my code will to this:

```
if ($(window).width() < 1200) {
    $("#spanInfo").appendTo(".page-heading");
    $(".maintenance-img").insertAfter(".maintenance-title");
    $(".experience-shop-img").insertBefore(".experience-shop");
}
```

And I will say that this kind of does the job?, but I would like to create a real-time function that checks if the resolution changes and if so it changes the order of the content blocks like the code above does.

Any help's appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Put your code within a window resize event handler. It's worth noting that CSS media queries are *much* better suited to re-arranging the layout based on window size, so I'd suggest investigating whether it's possible to do what you need in CSS alone

Comment: Indeed! There seems to be an option to change the order using a flexbox. I will try it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window on resize:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  var win = $(this); //this = window
  if (win.height() >= 820) { /* ... */ }
  if (win.width() >= 1280) { /* ... */ }
});
```

Hope this helps